# Where did my Debug Console's command prompt go?

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to use Pycharm's debug feature, but my favourite feature in the Debug Console has disappeared!

In fact, the entire bar which I've circled in the image below is gone:

[image]

Any ideas on how I might get it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

un-check "Emulate terminal in console output" in your active Run/Debug configuration.

(Reference https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-python.html?search=configuration)

original credit: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000244824-Console-toolbar-is-gone?page=1#community_comment_115000347810