# Show python prompt button missing PyCharm CE 2021.1.2, even after trying all suggested remedies

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, console

I am trying to debug my code, which is an automated script to navigate a website.  Ideally I would like to have access to a prompt or console while debugging so that I can test changes without re-running (Because the website requires a log in, if I re-run the code too many times it starts throwing captchas).

When I run the debugger and go to the console tab, I do not see a "Show Python Prompt" button, which according to the tutorial at approximately 2:17, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0, should be  visible.  I have already deselected "Emulate terminal in console output" as suggested here: [Where did my Debug Console's command prompt go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994202/where-did-my-debug-consoles-command-prompt-go).

This is what my side bar looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9iBY.png)

Have spent hours researching this and not sure what else to try! Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click this button - it's on by default. Your screenshot is a bit strange though - it looks like the execution has already finished.

[image]

If the Python process is over, you cannot interact with it. You either need to pause the execution on a breakpoint or enable the "Run with Python Console" option to use the console. The latter option is in the run configuration near the "Emulate terminal in console output". With "Run with Python Console", IDE will drop into the REPL after the script execution is complete allowing you to experiment further.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!  If the script execution causes a failure (and I did not set any breakpoints) shoudn't I be able to experiment within the console? I think this is what I can't get to work, even though I do have Run with Python Console enabled. Otherwise, breakpoints do work and allow me to experiment, so if I can't get it to work, I will be happy to continue doing it this way. Thank you again!

Comment: I guess it depends on the failure type. In general, the execution should indeed pause on termination exception. Check **Run | View Breakpoints | Python Exception Breakpoint | Any Exception** - do you have the "On termination" option enabled?